# Display out of stock products in WooCommerce

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, e-commerce

Is there a way to still display out of stock products on my WooCommerce website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to WooCommerce / Settings / Products / Inventory
– turn off “Out of Stock Visibility – Hide out of stock items from the catalog”